# Performing a series of async json fetch requests where each relies on a variable from the preceding fetch. Best approach?

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, fetch-api

I am doing a series of *async await* fetch requests, each one relying on a variable found in the preceding request. The way I have it set up now is through a series of dedicated functions that each return the variable I need. I subsequently have a .then chain, where the relevant variable is passed on, used, and finally placed in the html. These chains can sometimes contain up to 6 functions.

It might look something like this:

```
fetch1(artist_name) //returns an artistID 
  .then(artistID => fetch2(artistID, albumName))  //uses the artistID and album name to return a trackID
  .then(trackID => fetch3(trackID)) //uses the trackID to return track credits
```

(result1)

```
 fetch1(artist_name)
   .then(artistID => fetch2(artistID, albumName))
   .then(trackName => fetch4(trackName))
```

(result2)

This works fine, but I am curious whether this is the most efficient way to proceed, because for result 1 and 2, I repeat fetch1 and fetch2, relying on the same JSON object returned after the 2nd fetch to do my third fetch:

**fetch1 > fetch2** > fetch3 > result 1

**fetch1 > fetch2** > fetch4 > result 2

Can anyone point me to a resource, or provide an example of how this can be better achieved? I am aware that javascript works asynchronously (hence the async fetch).

My fetch requests all generally look like this:

```
async function fetch1(artist_name) {
  try {
    var url = `http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?&fmt=json&limit=1&query=artist:"${artist_name}"`
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json()
    let mbArtistID = data["artists"][0].id
    return mbArtistID
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```